# Removing Commas between Hashtags on WordPress on Astra theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried all possible ways to remove the (commas ,) between the tags on my Wordpress website but I haven't had any luck.

URL: https://www.content-whale.com/blog/

[Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcCCm.png)

**PHP**

```
add_filter('the_tags', 'remove_tag_commas', 10, 2);
function remove_tag_commas($tags, $post_id) {
    $tags_string = implode(', ', $tags); // Convert tags array to a comma-separated string
    $tags_string = str_replace(', ,', ',', $tags_string); // Remove consecutive commas
    
    // Convert the modified string back to an array of tags
    $modified_tags = explode(', ', $tags_string);
    
    return $modified_tags;
}
```

**OR**

**Javascript**

```
const container = document.querySelector('.premium-blog-post-tags-container');
const tags = Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('.premium-blog-post-tags-container a[rel]'));

tags.forEach((tag, index) => {
  tag.textContent = tag.textContent.replace(/,\s*/g, '');

  if (index !== tags.length - 1) {
    const comma = tag.nextSibling;
    if (comma && comma.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && comma.textContent.trim() === ',') {
      comma.remove();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you try modifying the theme files? It’s probably in one of the template files there.

Comment: Yes I did, it doesn't work & plus it's a client project so they keep updating the theme. Is there no other way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't seem to have control over template files, but you did try to use Javscript, you could add the following Javascript. It checks the content of the `.premium-blog-post-tags-container` `div`s whether they are text nodes and not links. Then removes those text nodes, so you will end up with only the links and not the text nodes.

```js
let categoryLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('premium-blog-post-tags-container');
for(let i = 0; i < categoryLinks.length; i++){
    let childNodes = categoryLinks[i].childNodes;
    for(let c = 0; c < childNodes.length; c++){
        if(childNodes[c].nodeName === "#text"){
            categoryLinks[i].removeChild(childNodes[c]);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="premium-blog-post-tags-container">
    <i class="fa fa-tags fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <a>article writing services</a>, <a>article</a>, , , , , , , , , ,                      
</div>
```

Comment: This worked well. Appreicate your help